# How to determine if an array is in a stack?

Tags: c#, arrays, stack, contains, any

So I am trying to determine if an array of identical values is within a stack.

```
Stack<string> stackOfStrings = new Stack<string>();
stackOfStrings.Push("dog");
stackOfStrings.Push("cat");
Debug.WriteLine("stackOfString contains cat: " + 
    stackOfStrings.Contains("cat"));
Debug.WriteLine("stackOfString contains dog: " + 
    stackOfStrings.Contains("dog"));

Stack<int[]> stackOfIntArrays = new Stack<int[]>();
stackOfIntArrays.Push(new int[]{0,1});
stackOfIntArrays.Push(new int[]{1,1});
int[] array01 = new int[]{0,1};
int[] anotherArray01 = new int[]{0,1};
int[] array11 = new int[] { 1, 1 };

Debug.WriteLine("SequenceEqual can compare arrays of identical value: " + array01.SequenceEqual(anotherArray01));
Debug.WriteLine("SequenceEqual can be used to compare the top value of a stack: " + stackOfIntArrays.Peek().SequenceEqual(array11));
//I want the line below to evaluate to true 
Debug.WriteLine("Contains can be used to determine if an array of values is within the stack: " + stackOfIntArrays.Contains(array01));
```

Here is the output for code as it is:

```
stackOfString contains cat: True
stackOfString contains dog: True
SequenceEqual can compare arrays of identical value: True
SequenceEqual can be used to compare the top value of a stack: True
Contains can be used to determine if an array of values is within the stack: False
```

My research into this has turned up a lot of results for seeing if an array is in another array or is a subset of another array, which is how I learned about SequenceEqual. Seeing how that seems to only be able to check the top value in the stack it is inadequate for what I want.

An alternative solution I've considered would be to restack the stack to a new stack and checking each array as it is moved over. However, considering that contains can look throughout an entire stack for values of type string leaves me with the conclusion that it should be possible for values of type int[]. If not, guidance on the best possible workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: You wish to know if **any** element of the stack is **sequence equal** to a particular value.  Does that give you an idea of how to implement it?

Comment: If you want Contains() to work then you need to bring need an IEqualityComparer that does more than the default one, which only checks for object identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ's [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Contains` for containment checks on conditions other than equality:

```
Debug.WriteLine(
    "Enumerable.Any can be used to determine if an array of values is within the stack: {0}"
,   stackOfIntArrays.Any(a => array01. SequenceEqual(a))
);
```

This amounts to a "contains if ..." implementation for an arbitrary condition.

Comment: @EricLippert You are right, I copy-pasted OP's string without reading it. Thank you!